# What is happening with unassigned C arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

This is my first StackOverflow quesiton, and I'm sorry if I'm messing up a bit. Here's a small note: I just started learning C (like just a few days ago, from w3schools). Today, I was experimenting with C arrays, and tried to read the values of an array that was declared but not assigned to anything. I expected the output to be 0s, but it was random numbers.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int test[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", test[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have declared an array `test` but haven't assigned it to anything. When I read its values, I expected to find 0s, but here's the output

```
0
0
-1787751399
32759
8
0
11
0
29823880
702
```

I tried searching for it, but my lack of experience led me nowhere. I did come across something about a hotel room and a book, but I didn't really understand it. I would really appreciate some help, thanks!

*EDIT:* A great thanks to all the users who've answered this question, rly grateful to you all. I also read up a bit more on unintended behaviour and memory duration, like the answers suggested. Once again, thank you all!

Comment: *but haven't assigned it to anything*. Local variables are not initialised: you must do that yourself, for example `int test[10] = { 0 };`

Comment: When C was created, it was designed for efficiency, so avoids doing things that are not always needed. You're expected to do things when you need to. Arrays have no size information, you're expected to store that - if you need it. It doesn't check out of bounds indexes, you're expected to - if you need it. It doesn't manage allocate and free heap memory, you're expected to - if you need it. It won't do anything you don't need, making it faster, but making you do those things makes your code more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables in C have something called *storage duration*, essentially meaning "how is this variable initialized and how long can I expect it to live?"

- *Static storage duration*: all variables declared outside of any function (at *file scope*) as well as all variables declared as `static`.

  Unless initialized explicitly by the programmer, these variables are guaranteed to be initialized to zero/null pointers *before* main() starts.

  These variables will be valid throughout the whole execution of the program.
- *Automatic storage duration*: all variables declared inside a function between a `{` and a `}` (as well as function parameters).

  Unless initialized explicitly by the programmer, these variables have no guarantees of what value they will contain. They have so called "indeterminate values", essentially garbage. Using such a value can give any result and you might even get different results each time you use an indeterminate value.

  These variables will only be valid until you reach the `}` in the block where they were declared.
- *Allocated storage duration*: all variables explicitly allocated with `malloc` family of functions.

  In case you used `malloc`, the allocated chunk holds indeterminate values. In case you used `calloc`, the allocated chunk is initialized to all zeroes.

  These variables will stay valid until the point where you explicilty call `free()`.

(There's also thread storage but I won't go into that here.)

The reason why some of these scenarios result in uninitialized data with indeterminate "garbage" values is mainly performance reasons. Initializing something to all zeroes takes execution time. `malloc` is therefore always faster than `calloc` for example.

Comment: *These variables will only be valid until you reach the } in the block where they were declared*... there is one exception: variables declared in the first clause of `for` statements, for which the scope ends at the end of the statement.

Comment: @chqrlie Yeah and also function parameters, that are strictly speaking declared outside `{ }` but will become invalid at the `}` at the end of the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

It is Undefined Behaviour and the C standard does not say what will happen if you execute such code. Anything may happen, the compiler may even discard the whole block

Annex J - undefined behavior:

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while
> it is indeterminate (6.2.4,
> 6.7.9, 6.8).